# Nginx rewrite proxy_pass SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

So if I'm running proxy_pass with ssl but with no rewrites then everything work fine. Few lines from Nginx config:

```
location /v3 {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```

That proxy_pass will work with `/v3` and `/v3/something` as expected.

And here is updated one with rewrite which is ignoring actual rewrite:

```
location /v3 {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_pass https://example.com/somethingelse;
}
```

I'm expecting that if I'll request `/v3` from Nginx then it will return page from `https://example.com/somethingelse` while its returning page from `https://example.com/v3`

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you reload/restart the Nginx service? (What you did is not called a "rewrite".)

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yes I'm restarting nginx after every config update. Why its not a rewrite?

Comment: Because Nginx has [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite); as it is another feature it makes people think you are talking about that despite this question is about reverse proxying.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I'm not using separate rewrite directive but when you add URI to proxy_pass (like `/somethingelse` in my config) it should act as rewrite

Comment: And I've tried to use "plain" proxy pass with separate rewrite directive and got same result